# IllegalAccessError when running instrumentation tests on Android 19

Tags: android, android-multidex

I only tried on Android 19 and 21, and it's working on 21 while failing on 19, but I've got the feeling it will fail for any android < 21.

While running Instrumentation Tests I receive the following output:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.IllegalAccessError
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

I even tried to run them manually, same output. This is the command I use to run tests:

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.example.tests/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

The same APKs does not have any problems when tested on android 21.

I tried to verify the classes in classes.dex, the outcome was that:

I do not have any duplication of classes in the app apk

I do not have any duplication of classes in the test apk

I do have the following duplicates with all the classes combined from **both the app and test apk**:

1. Multidex Support library
2. Support v4
3. Appcompat v7

Should I remove those dependencies from the test apk? (I'm not sure this would work...)
What do you think can be done to solve this problem or at least to get more verbosity?

One important detail:

This problem started **the moment in which multidex support was added**.

Following is the Gradle android plugin version used:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

Comment: which version of the gradle android plugin are you using ?

Comment: Added to the post, 1.5.0 anyway.

Comment: and you probably using 1.0.1 as dependency for multidex ?